# Ploting dates on x-axis in octave: "error: __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match"

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, mismatch

I'm trying to plot 3 lines on the same figure with dates on X-axis . I can do it perfectly on without having dates on x-axis but when I try to put years on x-axis I get this error :

```
    error: __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match
```

I'm not familiar with MATLAB and this is my first tiral , here is the part of my code where I try to plot :

```
        data = importdata('2.txt');
        C = data.data.';
        C = C';

        N = length(C);
        H = 12;

        w = ones(2 * H + 1, 1);


       Lambda_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
       L_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
       U_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
       for t = (H+1):(N-H-1)
          Lambda_Tilde(t) = sum(w .* C(t-H:t+H)) / sum(w);
          L_Tilde(t) = poissinv(0.005, Lambda_Tilde(t));
          U_Tilde(t) = poissinv(0.995, Lambda_Tilde(t));
       end



      clf
      f=figure();
      t= (1996 : 2007);
      dateFormat = 10;
      datetick('x',dateFormat)
      plot(datenum(t,1,1), C, 'co*');
      hold on
      plot(datenum(t,1,1) , L_Tilde, 'g-.');
      plot(datenum(t,1,1) , U_Tilde, 'g-.');
      pause;
```

Now I understood where the problem is . C is a 1*144 Matrix, so is there a way to try to plot

```
     plot(1:N , C , 'co*' )
```

and having dates on xaxis instead of having random numbers? 
I will appreciate any guidance .

Comment: Can you please show us what value have L_Tilde, U_Tilde, and C?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, of course. I've edited the question. check the edited one please.

Comment: mmm Some example of C? your problem may be due to different lengths of t and C in line       plot(datenum(t,1,1), C, 'co*');

Comment: @AnderBiguri C is the second column of a text file .  144 different integres . the first column of this text file contains the dates but because I couldn't extract it . I decided to plot like this.

Comment: Then your problem is definitely where I told you. datenum(t,1,1) is a 1x12 matrix. if C is 1x144 you can not plot them together! X and Y variables should be the same length!

Comment: @AnderBiguri so I should define t as 12 months of these 12 years this way I have also 144 length ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is change the shape of t so that it is a 1x144 matrix with repeated dates in it (1996 12x, 1997 12x etc).  Then you can plot(t,C) and it should work.  To change the shape, you can use:

```
dates = [1996:2007];  %Creates the original dates matrix (your t)
N = size(dates,2);    %finds the length of that matrix (12 in your case)
M = 12;               %sets the number of repetitions
dates= repmat(dates,M,1);     %repeats each date M times, but they are still listed in columns
dates = reshape(dates,N*M,1); %changes the shape from columns containing the same shape to 1 column
```

Comment: Thank you , it's great . now I just ran into another problem which is that I'm running over a loop this program and I just found out my text files doesn't have the same dimension , I mean there are also files with 131 elements . so I need to make it work also for a matrix of 1*131 .