# How to put date ticks on x axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, date, plot

I have a text file consisted of two columns , the first column contains the date (in this format yyyy-mm) and the second column is an integer . the text file is a matrix of 2*144 like this :

```
   1996-06   23
   1996-07   53
   1996-08   12
   1996-09   21
   ...
```

By importdata I just read the second column of the file and I do some operation over the second column but at last they still remain 144. I can plot the results with random numbers on x axis but I can't plot dates on x axis as I need a vector of the same size but I just want to tick 12 years from 1996 to 2007 not all the months on x axis .
I'm a newie to MATLAB and I will appreciate any advice .

Here is the complete version of my code and error and where I have found out the problem is that I need a matrix of 1*144 for dates :
[Ploting dates on x-axis in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240126/ploting-dates-on-x-axis-in-octave)

Comment: If each point you want to plot has a date associated with it, then create a date vector where the i^th element is the date associated with the i^th point you wan to plot. In general, when you call `plot( x, y )`, there has to be the same number of elements in `x` as there is in `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to import your date vector properly in the first place. So you get a `time` vector the same length than your data.

To do that, you can use `textscan` (instead of `importdata`), it gives you more control. So looking at the code you detail in your previous question, import your data by doing:

```
%% // Import your data (textscan gives you more control)
fid = fopen( '2.txt' , 'r') ;  %// open your file
data = textscan(fid,'%s %f') ; %// import the content
fclose(fid) ;                  %// close the file

%% // parse your variables
time = datenum( data{:,1} , 'yyyy-mm' ) ; %// convert text strings into matlab serial date format
C = data{:,2} ; %// isolate your variable
```

After that, you have the same variable in `C` that you got with `importdata`, but you also have your original time vector (the same length) in the variable `time`

Then run your calculations code (*not repeated here, just the same code you wrote*). Then at the time of display, use:

```
%% // display the results
f = figure;
plot( time , C , '.');
hold on
plot( time , L_Tilde, 'g-.');
plot( time , U_Tilde, 'g-.');
dateFormat = 10;
datetick('x',dateFormat)
```

tips: Use the `datetick` instruction **after** the plots (the `plot` command may reset your tick otherwise)
As written, this will only show the year, but since you imported your original date/time value, you can also choose a different `dateFormat` which would also display the month and year.

---

*EDIT:*
To complete the answer, based on comment. By default, Matlab spaces the ticks marks, grid lines and labels automatically, trying not to overload the figure by adding a tick at every data point. If you want to override this behavior and control the exact spacing or positions of the ticks, you have to tell Matlab where to place them.

To do that, we'll define a vector of dates, spaced according to your liking, then tell matlab to draw ticks only at these locations.

```
tickStep = 2 ; %// choose the number of years you want
tickDates = datenum( 1996:tickStep:2008 ,1,1) ; %// creates a vector of tick positions
set(gca, 'XTick' , tickDates , 'XTickLabel' , datestr(tickDates,'yyyy') ) %// set the position and label of each tick
```

You can change the year step to `1` or anything that look good for your figure. If you go this way, forget the last 2 lines of code in the solution above. No need to use `datetick` any more since we set the tick string (`XTickLabel`) on the same line where we force their positions (by setting `XTick`).

Have a look at the different [datestr format](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_formatOut) if you want to modify the output format.

Comment: Thank you . It sounds perfect,I've tried this one and now just another problem which is the x axis is divided into 1996,1997,2000,2001,2004,2005,2008 how can I get all the years or at least 2 years like 1996,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008 ? and about NAN characters,yes that's the way it is , it depends on the H , if H=12 then I suppose to have 12 NAN characters at the end and 11 NAN characters at first :)

Comment: @Singu, I edited the answer to solve your tick spacing issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment of AnonSubmitter85, I would say you must use the function datetick after having generated the plot. The steps I think you need to take are:

1. Import the date data as cell of strings using importdata.
2. Create a serial time vector by passing that cell array to the datenum function:

> > datevect = datenum(cellofdatestrings, 'yyyy-mm')
> >
> > Call the plot function:
> >        plot(datevect, ydata)
> >
> > Apply date strings to tick marks of axis
> >        datetick('x', 'yy-mm')